# Get the height and width of available space in the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several div inside a div, I need to get the height and width of the empty space inside the main div.

I do not have the javascript yet, since I do not know where to start.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="w1">

        </div>
        <div class="w2 h2">

        </div>
        <div class="w3 h2"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
        div {
             border:1px solid #000;
             width:1000px;
             height:1000px;
             position:relative;             
        }

        div div {
            border:1px solid red;
            float:left;
            height:300px
        }

        .w1 {
            width:600px
        }

        .w2 {
            width:395px;
        }

        .w3 {
            width:300px;
            top:-300px;
        }

        .h2 {
            height:600px;
        }
    </style>
```

Any one has an idea how to get this?

[image]

Comment: It would be good if you can place some code..

Comment: Also, provide your html format.....

Comment: how do you expect to get irregular width of empty spaces???

Comment: if you have two div for the black div it's easy to get by calculating main div height/width by deducting left,right,top,bottom width/height......

Comment: How did you position those `div`s in the way like in the diagram...?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I think the OP has no div for the empty spaces...

Comment: @C-link - Oh I didn't notice those black boxes are actually empty space :P

Comment: If you need the dimensions of those rectangles, just use the geometry stuff you learned from high school to derive the values.

Comment: Since the OP has no div for the empty spaces, it can't be done to get width and height as there is irregular width

Comment: Thank you for posting your ideas. I think the positive comments is enough to get me started. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the event resize for calculating height and width of all div when resize window and when page is loaded

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      window.onresize = function () {
          RefreshSize();
      }

      RefreshSize();
});
```

then if every div has an id, use height and width

```
function RefreshSize(){
     var wCenterDiv = $(window).width() - $("#oneDiv").width() - $("#secondDiv").width();

     var hCenterDiv = $(window).height() - $("#oneDiv").height() - $("#secondDiv").height();
}
```

and so on

look this example

http://jsfiddle.net/7W7b9/

Comment: The OP has empty space i.e. the black div, how could you get it's width???

Comment: when page is loaded the width and height of window is calculated by browser. if div have a size, then you can substract from the window size, the size of div.

Comment: you didn't understand the question properly, please re-read the question

Comment: This is enough to give me an idea. Thank you so much...

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the main area by making

```
var area = $('#mainDiv').height() * $('#mainDiv').width()
```

Then calculate each child div's areas and add them

```
var subarea = 0;
$("#mainDiv > div").each(function(){
   subarea += $(this).height() * $(this).width()
});
```

Get the empty area

```
var emptyArea = area - subarea
```

You will tell me : this is an area, not the width and height.

In the example you gave, the empty space isn't a rectangle. So it doesn't have a simple width and height. What you can get is it's area.

Now, you may want two separated width/height values which represents the two rectangles in your empty space. Please specify it in your question. And please add numbers/IDs to your image example so that we can give you a precise answer.